# Performance string vs int values

Tags: mongodb, search

I inherited a Mongo database that presently stores enumerated values as strings.  It makes for nice, readable data but my concern is the performance of the database as it grows.  Does the overhead for searching/filtering on string vs integer values present scaling issues for Mongo beyond the fact that a variable length string value is going to take up more storage & memory than an integer value?

For Example:

```
{           
    $match: {
        "UnitOfMeasure" : { $eq :'Metric' }
}
```

vs

```
{           
    $match: {
        "UnitOfMeasure" : { $eq : 100 }
}
```

Comment: At the most basic point, strings require more memory to store than numeric or pure byte values. As for your ["which is best" question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), then it's not really up to us to tell you since it's purely up to your application. Certainly if you have strings that "look like numbers" or would otherwise lend themselves to "numeric ordering" then sure. But without context, this is simply asking for opinions. *"I prefer Coke over Pepsi"*, so there you go.

Comment: @NeilLunn  Thanks for the feedback, I've re-phrased the question based on your answer.  Other than the additional storage requirements for a string value is there a performance difference between a properly indexed string field and an integer field?